# How to read a png image from an encoded bytearray and store it into a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

My python socked receives a PNG image as encoded `bytearray`.
The image originally has `RGBA32` format and a resolution of `160 x 90`. After encoding it, I receive a `bytearray` with a length of `31529` (as opposed to the raw data size, which should be `160 * 90 * 4 = 57600`) bytes.

How can I decode this `bytearray` again and 1) display it with the PIL library and 2) convert it to a numpy array to work with the data?

I tried using the Image module from PIL (with `received_data` being my `bytearray`):

```
import PIL.Image as Image
# socket code...
Image.frombytes('RGBA', (160, 90), received_data)
```

but get the following error:

> argument 1 must be read-only bytes-like object, not bytearray

**Edit:**
Following  @thshea suggestion, I changed the code to
`Image.frombytes('RGBA', (160, 90), bytes(received_data))`, which resolves the error above. However, the function still seems to expect raw image data and I get the this error:

> not enough image data

Furthermore, I think this is meant to take raw data, with the option to write a custom decoder?

Comment: Try `bytes(recieved_data)` to turn the bytearray to bytes.

Comment: @thshea thank you, this solves the error, however the function still expects raw data and now I get a `not enough image data` error. Anyway, I will update the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably some better way, but wrapping the bytearray in a `BytesIO` object and giving it to PIL as an open file should do it:

```
import io
f = io.BytesIO(received_data)
im = Image.open(f)
```